# SASS/ SCSS - Unknown Encoding Format

Tags: sass, character-encoding, file-format

I am using the Brackets text editor and I have been using SASS. An unexpected computer reboot affected the file's encoding and my CSS code was replaced by diamonds with question marks.

I am getting the error "unknown encoding format", whenever I try opening my SCSS file. The content became rows of 0s instead of my code. I have also tried opening my SCSS file using different editors such as Sublime and Notepad++, all results are same.

What could be the cause of this? I cannot attach screenshots due to new account limitations.

Comment: When you "tried opening my .scss file using different editors such as sublime and notepadd++" did they open? Also, to be honest, I am not sure if this question is for SO...

Comment: Most likely you hadn't set the file's encoding to UTF-8. You should change its encoding and it will be fixed. Also, you need to set this encoding as default on your text editor / IDE.

Comment: Hi! I just updated my question

Comment: You should try what @moughamir suggests below.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your file encoding to UTF-8. try this utility [EmEditor](https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/versatility/multiple-file-encoding-conversions/).