# Error Opening CSS File - Unknown Encoding Format

Tags: html, css

I am working on creating a landing page with HTML and CSS. While trying to opening style.css file on Brackets, I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred while trying to open the following files:
E:/App Landing Page/assets/css/styles.css
Unknown Encoding Format
```

I have tried to open the styles.css file on other editors, like Visual Studio Code. But still, I am getting the same error.

I have also tried to follow the solution mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423664/sass-scss-unknown-encoding-format) on Stack Overflow. But it doesn't fix the issue.

Here is the link to my styles.css file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qvc0GnboPKvhz_IFz3SXvQhPxMTaN9Lz

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: How did you make this CSS file? Open it in notepad or notepad++ and you will see why they say it's the wrong encoding.

Comment: I tried opening your file in Notepad++, All I see is just NULL characters.
Same is shown by vim on linux.
Your file seems corrupted.

Comment: @Sumit Is there any way to fix the the issue?

Comment: @Jesse I created the CSS file using Brackets. Earlier, there was no issue. But suddenly, the error occurs. There are lots of CSS codes in the file. Redoing the codes again will take a lot of time. What should I do?

Comment: The file is completely full of null characters, so no I would be very surprised if it is recoverable. Unfortunately, I'm not sure there is much you can do unless Brackets has some sort of way of keeping backups.

Comment: @Jesse That's really painful to hear. I will have to write all those codes again. :(

Comment: Sorry to hear man. I wish you luck and the minimum amount of hair pulling possible.

Comment: If you use any version control system like git, mercurial then you can recover, otherwise from a backup copy. Always use a version control system for any real/big project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of ***css*** rules in this *styles.css* file just open text editor > paste and save with **.css** extension.

If you don't have ***css*** rules try to convert this file to UTF-8 format(charset=utf-8).

hope this will help:
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en

Comment: When I tried to open the file on notepad, I don't see any code.

Comment: I tried with linux notepad. it just show unsupported characters. problem with the encoded format.

Comment: What should I do in this case? I have this line in html file: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`. Do I have to add different line of code in the css file to convert it to UTF-8 format?

Comment: @Ravisara the file is full of NULL characters. No amount of encoding changes are going to make it readable.

Comment: @Jesse yes,  shawn it seems like you have to rewrite it :|